# New to Regex - Need to match everything starting from specified word to specified work multiline

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to writing regex statements with js. I have the below output and need to match starting from "CallId: to BookingId" being each new row.

snippet: 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 BookingId: "" 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 CallId: 50 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 CallPriority: None 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 CallRate: 6000000 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 CallType: Video 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 CallbackNumber: "80003@10.0.0.1" 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 Direction: Incoming 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 DisconnectCause: "Normal" 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 DisconnectCauseCode: 16 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 DisconnectCauseOrigin: SIP 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 DisconnectCauseType: RemoteDisconnect 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 DisconnectCauseValue: 2 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 Dismissed: True 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 DisplayName: "80003" 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 Duration: 64 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 Encryption: "Aes-128" 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 Protocol: "Sip" 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 RemoteNumber: "sip:80003@10.0.0.1" 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 11 StartTime: "2018/12/07 01:16:18" 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 20 BookingId: "" 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 20 CallId: 51 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 20 CallPriority: None 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 20 CallRate: 6000000 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 20 CallType: Video 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 20 CallbackNumber: "80003@10.0.0.2" 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 20 Direction: Incoming 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 20 DisconnectCause: "Normal" 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 20 DisconnectCauseCode: 16 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 20 DisconnectCauseOrigin: SIP 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 20 DisconnectCauseType: RemoteDisconnect 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 20 DisconnectCauseValue: 2 
*h xHistory CallLogs Call 20 Dismissed: True

So a new row would be everything from CallId: to BookingId: and I'll later to do a separate regex to parse out the value of each row for every ":" so I need to identify each row first.

Comment: You want from the phrase "CallId" to the phrase "BookingId" or do you want the _line containing "CallId"_ to the _line containing "BookingId"_? If the latter, Regex is not what you want here.

Comment: Also, every "CallId" seems to be a different call from the following "BookingId". Are you sure this is what you want and that this isn't an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Answer (score 0):

this will capture

`CallId(.*?)BookingId`

and then from

`^([^:]+):(.*?)$`

you can capture the key and value

Thanks